# DAX RANKX for within Category

Tags: powerbi, dax

How to calculate ranking for within Category? Say we have sample data with the following expected results:

[image]

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WcisqzSwpVtJRSiwoyEkF0oZgHKuDJJWUmAeEQIYJEBuhypXn56QlpRYVVQLZpkBsjCqdnAGVMwNrB8mFpaanliQm5aSC5AvySxJL8lGsRZFPTiwqyi8BWwuzGkU+Py8zPw9Im0OsjgUA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Category = _t, Subcategory = _t, Sales = _t, Results = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Category", type text}, {"Subcategory", type text}, {"Sales", Int64.Type}, {"Results", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

I have roamed for hints [there](https://radacad.com/how-to-use-rankx-in-dax-part-2-of-3-calculated-measures). Based on the pattern shown there, I was able to cook the following code:

```
Rank within category =
RANKX (
    FILTER (
        ALL (
            'MyTable'[Category],
            'MyTable'[Subcategory]
        ),
        'MyTable'[Category]
            = MAX ( 'MyTable'[Category] )
    ),
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'MyTable'[Sales] )
    )
)
```

The code above produces expected results but I have no idea how it works. Can you please shed light on that?

**Update.**

I have found [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/bi/cracking-dax-the-earlier-and-rankx-functions/) an alternative simple approach which has elegant few lines, but again, the logic how it works remains a puzzling riddle for me. Can you explain it?

```
Rank within category using variables = 

VAR TotalSalesThisItem = [SalesMeasure] // a variable to hold each item's sales

// now count how many items have sales which match or exceed this
RETURN
    COUNTROWS (
        FILTER (
            ALL ( MyTable[Subcategory] ),
            [SalesMeasure] >= TotalSalesThisItem
        )
    )
```

The mystique thing about this code is how it knows what is the Category? Code mentions only Subcategory column. Yet it produces expected results.

Comment: Your update contains a measure that is not defined, so it is very hard to say why this is working.

Comment: It is just SalesMeasure = SUM( MyTable[Sales] )

Answer (score 2):

Your solution (the first one named [Rank within category]) will only work as a measure and not as a calculated column. It uses the filtercontext generated by the table visual.

The first paramater of the Rankx function returns that part of the complete table where the category is the same as the selected value in the visual (MAX ( 'MyTable'[Category] )) because the MAX-function is not affected by the ALL-function.

Then the second parameter (the [sales] in each row) will be ranked to the [sales] values in the returned table. You need the CALCULATE Function to use the filtercontext created by FILTER function.

This would a be cleaner and shorter way for your solution:

```
Rank within category =
RANKX (
    ALLEXCEPT ( MyTable, MyTable[Category] ),
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'MyTable'[Sales] ) )
)
```

Comment: It looks surprisingly promising. However I hate the function ALLEXCEPT as it requires hard coding of all dimensions that may affect the result. Its equivalent ALL and VALUES is way out simpler especially in long-term maintenance, if you add dimensions to your model. https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/using-allexcept-versus-all-and-values/ Moreover, ALLEXECPT produces results for all items, even for those with no sales https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58978358/dax-allexcept-to-sum-by-category-of-multiple-dimension-tables

Comment: Would you please care to check if you have any hints how to crack similar question https://stackoverflow.com/q/59155221/1903793

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, that seems very complicated and unintuitive to accomplish what you want. I've recreated your table (thanks for including the M code!) and wrote the following calculated table:

```
Ranked =
RANKX (
    FILTER (
        Table5,
        Table5[Category]
            = EARLIER ( Table5[Category] )
    ),
    Table5[Sales],
    ,
    ASC,
    DENSE
)
```

This gives the same output as your Results column. What is happinging here is that I am giving it a altered table, based on a FILTER statement where I am limiting the RANKX operation to all rows of that Category. EARLIER() refers to the column one level up in the calculation (it is evaluated for each row, with EARLIER you can reference a different column on that row).

If this helps you, please mark it as the solution :)

Comment: Thank you for submitting alternative solution. As the function EARLIER is said to be obsolete due to introduction of variables and is not recommended for performance reasons, it inspired me to find solution with variables. However you missed the point of my question. The question is how the solution I posed produces expected results. I asked how the gun fires, and you are gave me a bow for an answer.